# Cannot inject LoadBalanced annotated OAuth2RestTemplate

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-oauth2, spring-cloud-connectors

I am using Spring Cloud Angel.SR4. My Configuration class for creating an `OAuth2RestTemplate` bean is as follows:

```
@Configuration
public class OAuthClientConfiguration {
    @Autowired
    private MyClientCredentialsResourceDetails resource;

    public OAuthClientConfiguration() {
    }

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("MyOAuthRestTemplate")
    public OAuth2RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        return new OAuth2RestTemplate(this.resource);
    }
}
```

This configuration is totally fine since I am using this `RestTemplate` in a Feign `RequestInterceptor` for injecting access tokens to the feign requests. The problem is that when I annotate an autowired `OAuth2RestTemplate` with `@LoadBalanced` the dependency injection engine raises a `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException` exception. For example, the following would raise an exception:

```
@LoadBalanced
@Autowired
@Qualifier("MyOAuthRestTemplate")
private OAuth2RestTemplate restTemplate;
```

and when I remove the `@LoadBalanced`, everything works fine. What is wrong with `@LoadBalanced`? Do I need any additional configurations (I already have `@EnableEurekaClient`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a workaround. The problem was that I had misunderstood the `@LoadBalanced` annotation. This is just a qualifier for the auto-created load-balanced `RestTemplate` bean, and it would not create a proxy around the annotated `RestTemplate` for injecting the load balancing capability.

After seeing this https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-commons/blob/v1.0.3.RELEASE/spring-cloud-commons/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/client/loadbalancer/LoadBalancerAutoConfiguration.java, I revised my `OAuth2RestTemplate` bean definition as follows, and it solved the problem.

```
@Bean
@Qualifier("MyOAuthRestTemplate")
public OAuth2RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateCustomizer customizer) {
    OAuth2RestTemplate restTemplate = new OAuth2RestTemplate(this.resource);
    customizer.customize(restTemplate);
    return restTemplate;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I used @LoadBalanced with restTemplate in spring cloud with ribbon behind the scenes.

adding @LoadBalanced in the bean definition it works
like this:

in my class i have

```
@Autowired  
@LoadBalanced  
@Qualifier("bookRepositoryServiceRestTemplate") private RestTemplate bookRepositoryServiceRestTemplate;
```

and in my configuration class i have:

```
@Configuration
public class ServiceConfig {

    @Bean
    @LoadBalanced
    public RestTemplate bookRepositoryServiceRestTemplate(SpringClientFactory clientFactory, LoadBalancerClient loadBalancer){
        RibbonClientHttpRequestFactory ribbonClientHttpRequestFactory = new RibbonClientHttpRequestFactory(clientFactory,loadBalancer);
        return new RestTemplate(ribbonClientHttpRequestFactory);
    }
    ....

}
```

this works for me

I hope that this can help

Comment: You shouldn't need `@Qualifier("bookRepositoryServiceRestTemplate")`.

Comment: Yes I know it is just a my habit